# Call to undefined function Zend\Mail\Header\iconv_mime_decode()

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, mezzio

Currently I'm developing an application with Zend Expressive.
I'm using zend-mail to send a register email.

However, here's the code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail\Service;

use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions;
use Zend\Mail\Message;

class MailService
{
    private $transport;
    private $options;

public function __construct() {
    $this->transport = new Smtp();
    $this->options =  new SmtpOptions([
        'name' => 'XXXXXX',
        'host' => 'XXXXXX',
        'port' => 587,
        'connection_class'  => 'plain',
        'connection_config' => [
            'username'  => 'XXXXXX',
            'password'  => 'XXXXXX',
            'ssl'       => 'tls'
        ],
    ]);
    $this->transport->setOptions($this->options);
}

public function sendRegisterMail($email)
{
    $message = new Message();
    $message->addFrom('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX');
    $message->addTo($email);
    $message->setEncoding("UTF-8");
    $message->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
    $message->setSubject('Subject');
    $message->setBody('This is the Message Body');

    $this->transport->send($message);

}
}

?>
```

I got the above error message. ICONV is installed and working.

Here's the code for the call of this function:

```
public static function mimeDecodeValue($value)
{
    $decodedValue = iconv_mime_decode($value, ICONV_MIME_DECODE_CONTINUE_ON_ERROR, 'UTF-8');
    return $decodedValue;
}
```

Regards,
Unreality

Comment: where and how are you calling `mimeDecodeValue()`?

Comment: zend-mail/src/Header/Date.php is calling the function to assemble email headers.

 
$value = HeaderWrap::mimeDecodeValue($value);

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint on that line and check in a debugger what is happening in that line specific?

Comment: It's trying to jump into the middlewareDispatcher of the zend-stratigility component and then throws a throwable at line 222, stack trace incoming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enable extension=iconv.so in your php.ini file.

Comment: ok....I'm feeling stupid right now....you were right. Although iconv seemd to be activated it wasn't actually

Comment: For my excuse...docs say it is enabled by default, although it may be disabled by compiling with --without-iconv.

That was the issue.